# liferay-ui tabs: distinction between tabs in javascript

Tags: jsp, liferay

I have the following definition of an element "tabs" in liferay-ui (using liferay 6.0) in my JSP file.

```
<liferay-ui:tabs
    names="articles,book chapters,books"
    refresh="<%= false %>"
    param="tab" 
    url="<someURL>"
    value="<%=tab%>"
    onClick="clean()"
>
```

The function 'clean()' makes something I need when the tab changes, but with the onClick, it also activates when the user clicks in the active tab.

Do you know how could I make the distinction between the active tab and the others inside the script or just make it happen when the tab change to a different one?

Thanks in advance,

Luis.

Comment: How are you setting `tabsValues` attribute? Or what are you passing in `tab`?

Comment: I´m getting the tab from the request through java. The names are taken from a property file.

Comment: What does `tab` contain?

Comment: The name within the property file. It changes when the page refreshes, but not when the tab changes.

Comment: Using jQuery you can do it easily, as current `tab` has `active` class on it!

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? since I can´t identify the tab that is being clicked, I´m not getting with the correct way to do this :(

Comment: Can you share the generated html (for liferay-ui:tabs) using inspect element?

Comment: Hi Parkash, I got the solution doing what you said (using jquery and checking for the class "current"). I´ll write it here. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Pleased to help you, happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, sorted this out using JQuery referring to the class generated for the tabs element (.aui-tabview-list) and checking the class ".current".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aui-tabview-list li").click(function(){
        var isActualTab = $(this).hasClass("current");
        if(isActualTab != true){
             //code of the function
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks to Parkash for the help.